# How to Improve Python Code for Gaussian Quadrature

Tags: python

I am teaching myself Python and doing so by porting my R code into Python. The following is an R function to compute the weights and nodes that would be used for gauss-hermite quadrature assuming N(0,1). I have successfully translated this into the following python code.

However, I am interested in a critique in terms of how this code could become more optimal? For example, I'm filling in elements in the upper and lower portions of the matrix triangles using some indexing, which I assume could be improved.

Any suggestions welcome.

```
import numpy as np
def gaussQuadNormal(Q):
    y = np.sqrt(range(1,Q,1))
    m = np.diag([1.0]*Q)
    for i in range(Q-1):
        m[i,(i+1)] = y[i]
        m[(i+1),i] = y[i]    
    result = np.linalg.eig(m)
    nodes = 1 - result[0]
    weights = result[1][0]**2
    return(nodes, weights)

nodes, weights = gaussQuadNormal(10)
```

Answer (score 2):

Code looks nice, very good using numpy. My only recommendation is to try and avoid loops. Direct numpy operations are highly optimized C code and run much faster (normally). For example, index access could be done like this:

```
import numpy as np

x   = np.zeros((5,5))
ind = np.arange(4)
x[ind,ind+1] = 12
x[ind+1,ind] = 15
print(x)
```

The right hand side, of course, casts to the appropriate size. So if "12" was a 4 long vector then it would fill the 4 spots in the array.

Comment: Great recommendation and exactly what I was hoping for. Similar to R, loops are inefficient and your excellent suggestion vastly improves my code exercise. Thank you.